# Hibernate, PostgreSQL: how to search in an array column

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hql

I use the PostgreSQL table `agents`. It has a column `zip_codes character(5)[]` that stores the zip codes of the areas the agents are responsible for.

It stores `agent1` with the zip codes `{11111,22222}` and `agent2` with the zip code `{33333}`.

I want to look for all agents that are responsible for a special area.

Without Hibernate it is easy: `SELECT * FROM agents WHERE '11111' = ANY (zip_codes)` returns `agent1`.

But how do I make it with HQL? It does not know `any`. But if I use `in` instead, I will get wrong results: if I write `select agents from Agents as agents where '{11111}' in (agents.zip_codes)`, `agent1` will not be found. If I use `'{33333}'` instead, `agent2` will be found.

Of course I can search with something like (in sql) `WHERE zip_codes[1] = '11111' OR zip_codes[2] = '11111'` (arrays in PostgreSQL start with index 1), but this is not handy for many entries in zip_codes.

Comment: Share your table structure please, are zip codes saved in different table?

Comment: @VladHanzha no, they are stored inline.

Comment: This is a `text` field type for them? In that case the problem is that you're looking for {11111} with closing bracket, but your field also contains 22222. You should look for 11111 in that case, without brackets

Comment: Do you mean `select agents from Agents as agents where '11111' in (agents.zip_codes)`? Then PostgreSQL throws an error: `malformed array literal: "11111" ... Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can regist dailect like this

```
public class MyPostgresSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {
  public MyPostgresSQLDialect() {
    super();

    this.registerFunction( "array_any", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER,"ANY(?1)") );
    this.registerFunction( "array_array", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER,"array[?1]") );

  }
}
```

now you can use in hql

```
String hql = " from tablename" +
            " where year = :year and month = :month and :version = array_any(versions)";
```

remeber regist dailect in sessionFactory

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.test.MyPostgresSQLDialect</prop>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much better than my workaround, because I can use the IN clause for non array columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround with Hibernate Interceptor**

This is not a nice solution:

Write the hql query `select agents from Agents as agents where '11111' in (agents.zip_codes)` and use the Hibernate Interceptor

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

  @Override
  public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    return sql.replaceAll("\\s+in\\s*\\(", " = any (");
  }
}
```